# Interface language in reportviewer

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I'm using Reportviewer to view reports in an ASP.NET MVC application. The culture of my system and browser is French. When I open the report in Visual Studio or directly from the server (in the browser) the interface is in French. But when I use reportviewer, the interface is in English. How do I get it in French?

I have tried to set the culture of the page to french like this :

```
(`UICulture="fr-FR"`)
```

or the culture of the assembly from neutral to auto like this :

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=auto`...
```

but without results.

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
String reportFolder = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SSRSReportsFolder"].ToString();

rvSiteMapping.Height = Unit.Pixel(Convert.ToInt32(Request["Height"]) - 58);
rvSiteMapping.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;

rvSiteMapping.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://server/PREPROD/"); 
rvSiteMapping.ServerReport.ReportPath = String.Format("/{0}/{1}", reportFolder, Request["ReportName"].ToString());

rvSiteMapping.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

Comment: Check this article https://devillers.nl/blog/localizing-microsoft-reportviewer/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/aa992078(v=vs.100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to solve this by following this post : https://devillers.nl/blog/localizing-microsoft-reportviewer/

The idea is to implement some interfaces like this :

```
 public class FrenchReportViewerMessages : IReportViewerMessages, IReportViewerMessages2, IReportViewerMessages3
    {
        #region IReportViewerMessages Members

        // English value: Back to Parent Report
        public string BackButtonToolTip
        {
            get { return "Terug naar het vorige rapport"; }
        }
...
```

And adding the folowing to my web.config:

```
<add key="ReportViewerMessages" value="FrenchReportViewerMessages, MyAssembly" />
```

That seems to be the solution, but now i get an error :
The type 'FrenchReportViewerMessages, MyAssembly' could not be found

Comment: Solved by doing this : <add key="ReportViewerMessages" value="MyNameSpace.FrenchReportViewerMessages, MyAssembly" />